# expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

In controller current_user exists and is signed in, but request is unauthorized. Why is that?

```
module ControllerMacros

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user, company: FactoryBot.create(:company))
      sign_in user
    end
  end

end
```

rspec_helper.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'devise'
require 'support/controller_macros'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```

Users test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  describe "GET /api/v1/users" do
    login_user

    it "should get list of users" do
      get 'index'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

  end
end
```

Error:

Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)

This tests are passing and working fine:

```
   it "should have a current_user" do
      expect(subject.current_user).to_not eq(nil)
    end

    it "should be signed in" do
      expect(subject.user_signed_in?).to be true
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  describe "GET /api/v1/users" do
    it "should get list of users" do
      login_user
      get 'index'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: login_user` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

but I dont think this is a problem, I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "action name or route " do
...omitted for brevity
 it "should get list of users" do
      get 'index',  params: {}, headers: {...some_type_of_headers e.g BASIC, JWT}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
end
```